# Bitmap URI stays the same Android Out Of Memory Exception

Tags: android, exception, bitmap, uri, out-of-memory

I have a question i'm taking an image and uploading it to the server. For the first time it all works great.
But the 2nd time i'm taking a picture i'm getting an Out Of Memory Exception at this line:

```
_mPhoto = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                        .getBitmap(cr, _mUri);
```

If i'm debugging _mUri it's the same for the 1st one and the 2nd time. I think this shouldnt..

I'm getting this error: http://pastebin.com/uVduy3d9

These are my 3 methods used to take a picture:

First check if phone has a camera:

```
Camera cam = Camera.open();
    if (cam != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null
                && savedInstanceState.getBoolean("Layout")) {
            setContentView(R.layout.registration_edit);
            initializeAccountDetails((User) savedInstanceState
                    .getSerializable(EXTRA_MESSAGE));
            inAccountDetails = true;
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.step_4);
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.snap)).setOnClickListener(this);
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.rotate)).setOnClickListener(this);
            cam.stopPreview();
            cam.release();
            cam = null;
        }
    } else {
        if (savedInstanceState != null
                && savedInstanceState.getBoolean("Layout")) {
            setContentView(R.layout.registration_edit);
            initializeAccountDetails((User) savedInstanceState
                    .getSerializable(EXTRA_MESSAGE));
            inAccountDetails = true;
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.step_4b);
        }
    }
```

When clicking on the button Snap the following onClick event is fired:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.snap) {
        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/BandenAnalyse/Images/");
        if (directory.exists()) {
            Intent i = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "/BandenAnalyse/Images/IMG_" + _timeStamp + ".jpg");
            _mUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, _mUri);
            startActivityForResult(i, TAKE_PICTURE);
        } else {
            directory.mkdir();
            this.onClick(v);
        }
    } else {
        if (_mPhoto != null) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            _mPhoto = Bitmap.createBitmap(_mPhoto, 0, 0,
                    _mPhoto.getWidth(), _mPhoto.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo_holder))
                    .setImageBitmap(_mPhoto);
        }
    }
}
```

When the picture is taken the result method will be fired:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case TAKE_PICTURE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(_mUri, null);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            try {
                _mPhoto = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                        .getBitmap(cr, _mUri);

                Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                Point size = new Point();
                display.getSize(size);
                int width = size.x;
                int scale = _mPhoto.getWidth() / width;
                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inSampleSize = 8;
                Debug.out(PATH_TO_PHOTO);
                Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PATH_TO_PHOTO, o);

                _mPhoto = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                                            temp,
                                            _mPhoto.getWidth() / scale, _mPhoto.getHeight()
                                                    / scale, false);

                temp.recycle();
                ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo_holder))
                        .setImageBitmap(_mPhoto);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if using API greater or equal to 11 then "useLargeheapSpace=true" in your manifest.

Comment: It seems that you have a memory leak. You can use Memory Analyzer tool in Eclipse to find it. I would recommend you add _mPhoto.recycle() after setting the Bitmap and also that you define ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo_holder)) as a class level ImageView variable to prevent creating a new instance each time

Comment: I'm also supporting api's lower than 11. Above and equals to 11 works now quite nice thanks @AliImran

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah I'm going to try that now :)!

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah When i Recycle _mPhoto it still gets the error going to use the memory analyzer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i had to add:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

To my manifest file. This allowed me to do it multiple times.

Comment: This is what i suggested you in the above comment.